# Teradata replacing hyphens with boxes in SQL Assistant?

Tags: unicode, ascii, teradata, utf-16, teradata-sql-assistant

I have been trying to load data from Teradata tables to Excel files but the problem I'm encountering is that of special characters getting replaced by boxes. As can be seen in the image below, some hyphens and Turkish characters are getting replaced by boxes.

[Special character replaced by boxes in Teradata SQL Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VbfQ.png)

The connection by default uses the ASCII character set and I tried to use the below code to translate the string to unicode (since I want to eventually use UTF-16 encoding):

TRANSLATE(_UNICODE "Column Name" USING UNICODE_TO_UNICODE_NFKD WITH ERROR).

I am not quite sure what exactly is the problem here. What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: ASCII character set does not support most non-english characters, set your session to Unicaode.

Comment: Those are probably "en dash" not "hyphen"; they look very similar in many fonts. Session character set ASCII is actually [Teradata LATIN](https://docs.teradata.com/r/j4dzSri4DSHlIGdmgL_EvQ/zEzbFcglVUBXxUuTPeDK4Q) which is a Teradata-specific extended ASCII variant intended to support both LATIN1 and LATIN9 (but not identical to any of the ISO-8859 variants)

Comment: Also not clear why you'd want to decompose characters for display. That's more often done for comparisons.